# J2ME Tamil(UniCode) Character Display

Tags: java, unicode, java-me, netbeans-7, tamil

I tried a many way to print tamil character in J2ME application
 `வ` whose unicode value `U0BB5`.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.StringItem;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

/**
 * @author arun kumar non ascii
 */
public class SampleMidlet extends MIDlet {

    Display display;
    Form form = null;
    String ms = null;
    NewClass obj;

    public void startApp() {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        form = new Form("Unicode Test");
        byte[] b = new byte[2];
        b[0] = 0x0b;
        b[1] = (byte) 0xb5;
        try {
            form.append("type0" + "வ");
            form.append("type1" + new String(b, "UTF-16"));
            form.append("type2" + new StringItem("", "\u0bb5").getText());
            form.append("type3" + "\u0bb5");
            form.append("type4" + new StringBuffer("\u0bb5"));
            form.append("type5" + new StringBuffer().append((char) Integer.parseInt("2997", 10)));
            form.append("type6" + ((char) Integer.parseInt("0bb5", 16)));

            char[] text = new char[]{'\u0bb5'};
            form.append(new String(text));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        display.setCurrent(form);

    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }
}
```

but all the time it shows  white box alone as shown.
[image: OnMicroEmultor]

where as in Netbeans emulator also shows the same, I'm targeting configuration for CLDC 1.1 and MIDP 2.0 .How to display that character without using Bitmap font (Image)file of that character ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with comment proper bitmap file can capable to produce the font on j2me app.
[MJbookmaker](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8j-6CFq6hsGc3NaaGxBMmVmVGs/edit?usp=sharing) is capable tool which produce desire format for j2me application

Answer (score 0):

Square boxes normally mean that the Font is unable to display that character. The encoding is fine, but you need a different Font.

This link explains how to change the Fonts on the emulator: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/J2ME-and-Unicode/1/

Comment: of course its unable to display that character,My question is how to display that one on mobile.

Comment: have added link to answer. Not sure how you get new fonts on to the phone though, but that should work with the emulator.

Comment: I already came across that link  it works for japanese,Arabic on emulator not for Tamil,but though tamil is unicode why it is not supporting.don't you seem the code where merely same

Comment: Why the down vote? Seems a little harsh. Fonts are the problem, and weren't mentioned in the question.

Comment: question is about displaying Unicode character ,font or visual glyph are inter related to the question,

Comment: @arun I have no idea how you expect to *display* a character without a *visual* glyph.

Comment: did i said anything without visual glyph? i just need to display character in any feasible way.

Comment: As far as I was told, J2ME only supports a subset of the unicode characters. So Tamil might very well just not be supported. When/if you see Tamil in apps/games, they're most probably created using bitmap fonts. That means, a PNG file containing all the characters + some code to render a String using those characters. It's not that difficult to code. Sadly though, I don't think you can use a bitmap font on a highlevel app (meaning one that uses Forms). I think you'll need to use Canvas/GameCanvas when using Bitmap fonts.